# Continue execution in Cucumber in case of any errors

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, watir-webdriver

I'm building an automation suite using Ruby/Selenium-WebDriver/Cucumber. What I want to achieve is to resume the cucumber scenario in case of any unexpected errors.

For e.g. Unexpected pop-ups

I might get a modal dialog at any point in the application. I want my code to close the pop-ups whenever the exception occurs and resume the execution.

The point of doing this is, the automation suite will run for multiple days on multiple systems. There won't be any kind of monitoring except logs and output reports. I don't want these unwanted exception to hamper the execution.

Comment: Isn't the point of automated testing to find unexpected errors? You could `rescue` the exceptions in the step definitions, but that's not standard BDD.  Here's an example that might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26761624/how-to-make-cucumber-test-continue-running-scenarios-when-rspec-expectationnotme

Comment: It might help if you can give an example. Usually an error prevents you from completing the rest of the scenario, so it is unclear what you are trying to resume. The one scenario I can see wanting to continue is if you have a series of assertions in the same scenario (but I'm not sure if that is considered an unexpected error).

Comment: ok.. for example.. I don't know at which point the application throws a pop-up. Now, i want to do something which can close the pop-up and resume the execution.

Comment: @orde -> I've the exceptions handled for few cases in step definitions. But  I can't write a begin rescue block for each code to handle the unexpected scenarios.

Comment: @yudi2312, when you say the popup can occur at any point, do you literally mean at any point or randomly when a user takes an action (like after clicking a link)? I ask because, Watir-Webdriver has a couple of different mechanisms for performing additional actions before/after an action. Which one would be useful would depend on exactly when the dialog can occur.

Comment: @Justin -> Yes I mean randomly and maybe also more than 1 pop-ups. I've a step build to take care of all the pop-ups at a particular instance. But  not sure how to execute it whenever I want to recover the execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that the alerts can be opened at any time, the best option may be to use an `AbstractEventListener`. This allows you to perform actions before (or after) Selenium interacts with the browser. This means that you could call your alert closing code right before each interaction.

The sample event listener would be defined like:

```
class AlertListener < Selenium::WebDriver::Support::AbstractEventListener
  def close_alerts(driver)
    # Assuming you want to handle the dialogs using Watir code instead of Selenium,
    # convert the Selenium::WebDriver to a Watir::Browser
    browser = Watir::Browser.new(driver)

    # Run whatever code you have for handling the dialog instances
    browser.alert.ok if browser.alert.exists?
  end

  def before_change_value_of(element, driver)
    close_alerts(driver)
  end

  def before_click(element, driver)
    close_alerts(driver)
  end

  def before_close(driver)
    close_alerts(driver)
  end

  def before_execute_script(script, driver)
    close_alerts(driver)
  end

  def before_find(by, what, driver)
    close_alerts(driver)
  end

  def before_navigate_back(driver)
    close_alerts(driver)
  end

  def before_navigate_forward(driver)
    close_alerts(driver)
  end

  def before_navigate_to(url, driver)
    close_alerts(driver)
  end

  def before_quit(driver)
    close_alerts(driver)
  end    
end
```

Note that you would replace the `close_alerts` method with whatever code you have already written for handling the alerts. The event listener is Selenium, which means you need to either write Selenium code or convert the element/driver to Watir (which is what is done in the example).

Once you have the listener created, you need to pass it to the browser during initialization:

```
listener = AlertListener.new
browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, :listener => listener
```

Comment: This looks interesting Justin. Let me try this piece. Thanks a lot for this reply.

Answer (score 0):

You could get your goal by accepting any alert that pops up on the `screen`.

You can do this in following steps:

```
Given(/^I should see the error message and accept it$/) do
  def alert_accept
    end
end
```

---

So whenever there is a popup it will accept it and continue forward.

You can find this step as well here:

https://github.com/ModusCreateOrg/cucumber-watir/blob/appium/features/step_definitions/appium_steps.rb

Comment: but this will be executed whenever the step is called right ? This is not what i want. I wan't to write this code at one place and let cucumber execute it whenever there is a alert in ui and continue with the execution after closing it.

Comment: Yes, this will be executed whenever this step is called. So you need to set this step on a place where you expect alert/error/popup to appear.

Comment: yeah... This will work only when we know where the error message can occur but not in case of unexpected alerts.

Comment: Why would anyone want to run automated tests and skip (not catch) unexpected error, I'm not getting the point of that goal?

Comment: Application throws pop-ups when the user performs an action and some back-end data is missing for the customer the automation suite is running. That pop-up will not impact the flow of the test case.